# How is Activity.Text encoded Microsoft Teams?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

I am writing a custom Teams bot. I got some questions about `Activity.Text` field:

- How is it encoded? I see some `<at>` tags when the bot is @mentioned, but I also see some `&#39;`. Can I use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`to decode it?
- Is there any document about the details of the `Activity.Text` field? The [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#a-idobjectsa-schema) says it is

> Text of the message that is sent from user to bot or bot to user. See the channel's documentation for limits imposed upon the contents of this property.

But it does not talk about the details about the field.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special about Activity.Text in Teams except for the  tags.  In general, depending on the Activity.TextFormat, the message you send might contain markdown or XML, but in general the message you receive from a user will be plain text.

Anything additional, like if the user sends bold text to your bot, can be extracted from the attachments object in the incoming payload, e.g. :

```
"attachments": [
    {
        "contentType": "text/html",
        "content": "<div><span itemscope=\"\" itemtype=\"http://schema.skype.com/Mention\" itemid=\"0\">Teams TestBot</span> |echo| <strong><strong>Hi</strong></strong>​​​​​​​</div>"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just found an interesting thing. I @mentioned my test echo bot and my custom bot, the attachment field is `EchoBot&#160;TeamsBot 11455` ,`contentType` is `text/html` while `Text` is `EchoBot TeamsBot 11455`. Why does the second space in attachment keep unescaped?